# If a subset of the primes has converging reciprocal sums, does it have relative density zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

If a subset $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ of the natural numbers has positive lower density, i.e. there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $\{N_k\}$ of natural numbers s.t. $$\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{\lvert A\cap \{1,\dots, N_k\}\rvert}{N_k}>\epsilon,\text{ then }\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{a}$$ diverges; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206871/can-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-a-set-without-density-converge).

In the course of a proof I'm writing, I'm trying to see if the same holds if we instead consider the relative density of a subset of the primes. Specifically: let $B\subset\mathbb{P}$ be a subset of the primes such that $$\sum_{b\in B}\frac{1}{b}<\infty.$$ Does it then follow that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\lvert B\cap\{1,\dots,N\}\rvert}{\pi(N)} = 0?$$ (Here $\pi(N)$ counts the number of primes not exceeding $N$).

Given that the sum of all reciprocals of the primes diverges and the first observation, I'm inclined to believe that the question can be answered in the positive, but I've had a hard time trying to imitate the proof of the linked post above to this scenario (using the contrapositive argument).

For what it's worth, the converse is not true, as shown [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174152/density-zero-subsets-of-primes) There are subsets of primes with zero relative density and diverging sum of reciprocals. I'd be grateful for any pointers or references (or counterexamples, if there are some).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you get with $$\bigcup_{k\ge 1} \{ p \text{ prime}, p\in [e^{e^k},2 e^{e^k}]\}$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll call this set $B$; it has a converging reciprocal sum. There is $k_0$ large enough and a constant $C>0$ that $$\pi(2e^{e^k})-\pi(e^{e^k})\geq Ce^{e^k - k}$$ by the PNT, and all primes in that interval are at least $e^{e^k}$, so $$\sum_{p\in B}\frac{1}{p}\leq\text{ finite} + \sum_{k\geq k_0}\frac{e^{e^k - k}}{e^{e^k}}<\infty.$$ On the other hand, by the same reasoning, $$\frac{\lvert\{1,\dots, \lfloor 2e^{e^N}\rfloor \}\cap B\rvert}{\pi\left(\lfloor 2e^{e^N}\rfloor\right)}\geq\frac{1}{2},$$ I believe. Nice counterexample, though a bit disappointing :)

Comment: The difference between the primes and the integers is that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\in [x,rx]} \frac1n= \log r$ while $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{p\in [x,rx]} \frac1p= 0$ @BenjaminMajor